# Complex vs. Real Total-variation Norms of Real Radon Measures

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, total-variation

Let $\mu$ be a **real** Radon measure over $\mathbb{R}$. Its total variation norm is given by
\begin{equation}
\lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})} = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}), \lVert f \rVert_\infty \leq 1} | \langle \mu , f \rangle |
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ is the space of real valued continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Looking at $\mu$ as a **complex** Radon measure, its total variation norm is now
\begin{equation}
\lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})} = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}), \lVert f \rVert_\infty \leq 1} | \langle \mu , f \rangle |
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$ is the space of complex valued continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Clearly, since $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \subset \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$, one has that $\lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})} \leq \lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})}$.

**Question:** Do we have that the real and complex norms are equal, i.e., $\lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})} = \lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})}$ for any real Radon measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard trick in complex analysis; pick a complex function for which $| \langle \mu , f \rangle |=a>0$; this means that there is $b \in [0, 2\pi]$ st $ \langle \mu , e^{ib}f \rangle =a$; let $g=e^{ib}f$ and conjugating and using that $\mu$ real, we get:

$\langle \mu , g \rangle =a$ and $\langle \mu , \bar g \rangle =a$ so summing:

$\langle \mu , \Re g \rangle =a$, hence we are done by letting $a_n \to \lVert \mu \rVert_{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})}, f_n$ apriori complex realizing the $a_n$ being replaced with the real functions $\Re g_n$ constructed above (and noting that all the required properties of $f$ are preserved by $g, \Re g$)